# R - identify cols that contain any of a values set

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(letters[1:4],"a"),col2 = 1:5,col3 = letters[10:14])
 df
  col1 col2 col3
1    a    1    j
2    b    2    k
3    c    3    l
4    d    4    m
5    a    5    n
```

I would like to identify the columns that contain any value from the following vector:

```
vals=c("a","b","n","w")
```

A tidy solution would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   select(where(~ any(. %in% vals, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
   col1 col3
1    a    j
2    b    k
3    c    l
4    d    m
5    a    n
```

---

A similar option in `base R` is with `Filter`

```
Filter(\(x)  any(x %in% vals, na.rm = TRUE), df)
  col1 col3
1    a    j
2    b    k
3    c    l
4    d    m
5    a    n
```

Answer (score 3):

Another tidyverse option is to use `keep()` from `purrr`.

```r
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  keep( ~ any(.x %in% vals))
```